# CSS first-letter formatting reducing gap between first and second character

Tags: html, css, character, paragraph, letter

I am using the following css :

```
p::first-letter {
    font-size: 400%;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

I want to reduce the gap between the first and the second character. For example in this [**website**](http://www.ananyabarta.com) I want to reduce the space between 'T' and 'h' in the first word 'Thakur'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
p::first-letter {
    letter-spacing: -8px;
}
```

Comment: I would use this approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can give negative right margin:

```css
p:first-letter{
  font-size: 400%;
  line-height: 0;
  margin-right:-2%;
}
```

```html
<p>Thakur</p>
```

You can give margin either in percentage or pixel. You can also use [letter-spacing](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/letter-spacing/) property as recommended by @parag-parmmar but it is better to give value in `%` because your font-size is relative. Refer [this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/letter-spacing/) post to know more about letter-spacing. You have given `font-size` in percentage. But, I would recommend you to look at rem units for font sizing. Have a look at [this](https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem) wonderful post.

Answer (score 2):

Use negative values for `margin-right`:

```
p::first-letter {
  margin-right: -5px;
}
```

```css
body, p, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7 {
  font-family: Cambria;
  font-size: 20px;
}

body {
  padding: 25px;
}
p {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

p::first-letter {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 -6px 0 0;
  font-size: 300%;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Thakur Anukulchandra was a highly accomplished spiritual teacher and the ideal of Netaji Subhash Chandra Bose. He was a very outspoken person yet extremly polite. He contributed more than 80 books on various subjects and many people have written biographies on Him, yet less is knows about Him. Ray A Hauserman, a US vetran of World War II became His disciple and later went on writing few books on Him. Eminent Indians like Deshbandhu Chittaranjan Das, Mahatma Gandhi, Lal Bahadur Shashtri, Shyama Prasad Mukherjee came to meet Thakur to acquire His blessings. People from different parts of the world and different walks of life like scientists, scholars, doctors, lawers, educationalists came to seek wisdom. Continue...</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a negative margin on `p::first-letter`. The value will depend on your specific circumstances.

```css
p {
  font-family: "Times"
}
p::first-letter {
  font-size: 400%;
  line-height: .25em;
}
p.dropcap::first-letter {
  margin-right: -.125em;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<p class="dropcap">Torem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime eius sapiente distinctio et, inventore voluptatum necessitatibus perspiciatis, dignissimos cumque, doloribus beatae aliquid deleniti at dolorum. Sunt soluta quae totam eligendi cumque consectetur
  ipsam, iste mollitia.</p>

<p>Torem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime eius sapiente distinctio et, inventore voluptatum necessitatibus perspiciatis, dignissimos cumque, doloribus beatae aliquid deleniti at dolorum. Sunt soluta quae totam eligendi cumque consectetur
  ipsam, iste mollitia.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This `margin: -5px;`

```
p.prophet::first-letter {
    margin: -5px;
    font-size: 400%;
    line-height: 0;

}
```